# Unable to register setting with defaults.py in app, it will not override Mezzanine's default setting

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I'm new to Django and Mezzanine. Referencing the [configuration](http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/configuration.html) docs for Mezzanine, I am unable to register a setting in defaults.py that overrides Mezzanine's default setting.

Here's my project structure:

```
mysite/
manage.py
dev.db
fabfile.py
__init__.py
local_settings.py
requirements.txt
settings.py
urls.py
wsgi.py
deploy/
    (files related to deployment)
theme/
    __init__.py
    admin.py
    models.py
    defaults.py
    static/
        (css, js, etc.)
    templates/
        (index.html, base.html, etc.)
    tests.py
    views.py
```

Here's order of the installed apps in mysite.settings

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
"theme",
"django.contrib.admin",
"django.contrib.auth",
"django.contrib.contenttypes",
"django.contrib.redirects",
"django.contrib.sessions",
"django.contrib.sites",
"django.contrib.sitemaps",
"django.contrib.staticfiles",
"cartridge.shop",
"mezzanine.boot",
"mezzanine.conf",
"mezzanine.core",
"mezzanine.generic",
"mezzanine.blog",
"mezzanine.forms",
"mezzanine.pages",
"mezzanine.galleries",
"mezzanine.twitter",
#"mezzanine.accounts",
#"mezzanine.mobile",
)
```

Here's mysite.theme.defaults

```
from mezzanine.conf import register_setting


register_setting(
    name="SITE_TAGLINE",
    description="What's the site about?",
    editable=True,
    default="Storm Chasing Team",
)
```

Could you help me understand why the defaults.py module in theme cannot override Mezzanine's default setting? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure about overriding defaults, but that setting is editable so you can go to Site -> Settings in your site's admin and change it.

Answer (score 1):

`TEMPLATE_ACCESSIBLE_SETTINGS` is also added to defaults.py and your defaults.py should look like this:

```
from mezzanine.conf import register_setting

register_setting(
    name="TEMPLATE_ACCESSIBLE_SETTINGS",
    append=True,
    default=("SITE_TAGLINE",),
)


register_setting(
    name="SITE_TAGLINE",
    description="What's the site about?",
    editable=True,
    default="Storm Chasing Team",
)
```